# addConditionalFormatting is not found in exceljs

Tags: angular, exceljs

I am using `exceljs 3.8.2`.
In [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#conditional-formatting)
there is an method `addConditionalFormatting` for conditional formatting. But after installation this method is not found.

I am using below code.

```
import { Workbook, Worksheet, Cell, Fill, Row } from 'exceljs';

worksheet.addConditionalFormatting({
      ref: 'A1:E7',
      rules: [
        {
          type: 'expression',
          formulae: ['MOD(ROW()+COLUMN(),2)=0'],
          style: {fill: {type: 'pattern', pattern: 'solid', bgColor: {argb: 'FF00FF00'}}},
        }
      ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It exists but may has been lost from index.d.ts file in 3.8.0. It was fixed in 3.9.0. Please update the dependency to resolve it.